# list export and import from csv

Tags: python, csv

i need to save 6 lists in csv file and load back when program open.help me please
this is one of my list and all the lists are updating these are some sample details

```
list_of_DVDsuppliers=[["a","m",15],["w","p",34]]
```

i tried this code but it wont work.

```
import csv
list_of_DVDsuppliers=[["a","m",15],["w","p",34]]
myfile = open("pppp.csv", 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

wr.writerow(list_of_DVDsuppliers)
myfile.close
```

1.help me to save and read in csv?

still need help.................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
wr.writerows(list_of_DVDsuppliers)
```

with an `s`, because you're writing more than one row.

As well,

```
myfile.close
```

doesn't do anything: you want

```
myfile.close()
```

to actually call it, not merely mention the name.

Better would be to use a `with` block:

```
with open("pppp.csv", "wb") as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    wr.writerows(list_of_DVDsuppliers)
```

because then you never have to remember to close the file, it's done automatically.

---

This produces a file looking like

```
a,m,15
w,p,34
```

which I'm guessing is what you want (you might want the list flattened and written as one row instead.)

[PS: I'm assuming Python 2 here.  Othewise it should be `open("pppp.csv", "r", newline='')`.]

Comment: it worked thanks a lot.but can you tell me how to export these details again to my program (as a list[coz i need to update details on the csv]) ?